# EndPoint will be marked SUSPENDED WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I don't know why my EndPoint was marked like SUSPENDED and my application does not receive return from Service.

This was shown on log:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:00:32,269]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/MonitoramentoServico.MonitoramentoServicoHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:BuscarCaminhoTask, SOAPAction: urn:BuscarCaminhoTask, MessageID: urn:uuid:78e22483-c74e-4673-8286-8a18294135b3, Direction: request {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:00:33,259]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-15546: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:00:33,260]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : MonitoramentoEndPoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:00:33,260]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : MonitoramentoEndPoint - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Sep 01 11:01:03 BRT 2014 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,196]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/MonitoramentoServico.MonitoramentoServicoHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:BuscaServicosMonitorar, SOAPAction: urn:BuscaServicosMonitorar, MessageID: urn:uuid:e5ce0a3c-e5d1-4364-a7aa-897363392c4d, Direction: request {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,203]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/MonitoramentoServico.MonitoramentoServicoHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:BuscaHardwaresMonitorar, SOAPAction: urn:BuscaHardwaresMonitorar, MessageID: urn:uuid:e74ab088-1eb0-47cc-8447-7b9e016edcec, Direction: request {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,208]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/MonitoramentoServico.MonitoramentoServicoHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:BuscarCaminhoTask, SOAPAction: urn:BuscarCaminhoTask, MessageID: urn:uuid:18dad64b-292e-4c79-908e-6d9b638e1d8a, Direction: request {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,291]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-15544: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,292]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : MonitoramentoEndPoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:01,292]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : MonitoramentoEndPoint - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Sep 01 11:01:31 BRT 2014 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 11:01:02,210]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-388 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
```

The EndPoint come back automatically after some seconds, but how can I know whats wrong?

This is the error after receive my request:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "POST /services/MonitoramentoDS HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "SOAPAction: "urn:UpdateServidor"[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Host: localhost:9763[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,746] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,747] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "19a[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><UpdateServidor xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><situacao>0</situacao><id>2</id><sithard>1</sithard><sitserv>1</sitserv><sittask>0</sittask></UpdateServidor></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Date: Mon, 01 Sep 2014 18:27:42 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,750] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-09-01 15:27:42,753] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: An access occurred that is not valid.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.InOnlyAxisOperation.getMessage(InOnlyAxisOperation.java:117)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:222)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint is getting suspended, when ESB could not send out message through that particular endpoint. You can find endpoint suspension parameters in your endpoint configuration.
Here if you see  `http-outgoing-15544: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE` occurs because, connection between  ESB and the backend server times out.  Default socket
timeout is 60 seconds. You can increase it to 120 seconds and check. To do that edit the
passthru-http.properties file as;

> http.socket.timeout=120000

And enable ESB wirelogs so you can find more info.
@ log4j properties file, add following line and restart the server.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Comment: The problem continue :/  I updated my question with the error after DEBUG log.